# Setting environment variable in C

Tags: c

I am trying to change my $PATH in a C program. After this code, when I print my PATH variable, it remains the same. Here is my approach,

```
    char path[100]="PATH=";
    char *input = "/newfolder/hello/";
    putenv(strcat(path, input));
```

I am trying to print it back out using echo $PATH and it still shows the former path, as in it is not changed.

Comment: You can't use 'echo $PATH' from within the same process. What exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please show me the way you get the environment variable after you set it up.
I've got the following C code working for me as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char path[100]="PATH=";
    char *input = "/newfolder/hello/";
    putenv(strcat(path, input));

    char* pPath;
    pPath = getenv("PATH");

    printf("%s", pPath);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is: `/newfolder/hello/`

> I am trying to print it back out using echo $PATH and it still shows the former path, as in it is not changed.

Is you using in your program something like:

```
system("echo $PATH");
```

Then you wouldn't get that value you have set, since this command will be executed and evaluated from your shell process which is still having initial environment variable set values.

Comment: I have my own shell which I am building and I call echo $PATH and it still prints old value

Comment: @user2098078 Then you are building it wrong. Something wrong with your code for `echo $PATH`. This is not a real question. Your contention is completely disproved by this answer.

Comment: echo $PATH prints out the proper former value and when I change it with putenv, and print it again it does not work

Comment: @user2098078 But if you've building the shell, it's your `echo` command. So it's wrong. So fix it.

Comment: This is the best answer so far; you demonstrate the code working.  I'm not clear, though, about the last section discussing `system("echo $PATH");` — that should launch a shell with the new environment (with a very minimal PATH; fortunately, `echo` is usually a shell built-in; trying to run `env` would not work, though running `/usr/bin/env` would).  Indeed, when I take your code, add the `system()` and run it, I see the reduced PATH.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, hmm, you are right. I've mixed up some things there, so I'd better cut the second part off. (but it's too late) :)

Answer (score 3):

When you start a process it gets a copy of its parent's environment.  You are changing the copy, which disappears when the program ends.

Comment: I am printing it within the same program. I know that once I close my C program it won't be permanently changed but for the time being, once I alter it, and I print it. It is not changed. I still see the former PATH.

Comment: You are printing it within the same program how?

Comment: @EJP I am building a shell, and in my shell, I call echo $PATH or echo PATH and it prints the PATH variable

Comment: @user2098078 So your home-grown `echo $PATH` does something wrong, obviously.

Comment: It is not homegrown. It is the ordinary one that you would pass using system

Comment: @user2098078 QED. *You are starting another process.* Not 'printing it within the same program'.

Comment: You need to export environment variables for your shell to get them.

Comment: ^Fixed it. Thanks Stark. EJP that is not true, you are wrong. What stark said fixed it

Comment: @markfiel Either you are executing your own internal echo code or you are executing the system echo command within a new process. Make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

`putenv()` will only change the environment for the running process. It cannot change the environment of the calling process (shell)

Comment: I know that and within the environment when I reprint it, it is not changed.

Comment: How do we change the environment of the calling process (shell)? when i try "cd filename" i want to access some other folders and not the current working directory. any idea how to do this one?

Comment: @grooot You need to ask your own question - not comment on an unrelated 8 year old one !